# Stabilize multiples part in a video

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor

Here is my problem, I have multiple videos I want to crop and combine to make one video. My problem is, most of these were filmed using handheld cameras, which resulted in shaky videos. I would like to stabilize them after they are combined but it doesn't seem Blender support this. Is there a way to stabilize without having to stabilize and render each video separately?

Comment: The only way you can stabilize a video (in blender and other software) is to analyze each of the clips and stabilize it independently. Once you have the tracking (stabilization) information you don't necessarily need to render each one of them, you can combine them using the compositor into a final clip. While it's possible to do this with blender, you might want to consider doing this in a real video editing program (premiere, resolve, FCP, etc...) It will be faster and less painful.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpIXqAepfxY

Comment: Thanks @cegaton, I will try to use Resolve to do the editing. Do you know if there is a better free video editing software that I could use then this? I sadly dont have the money to buy all the expensive stuff.

Comment: @jonapap what operating system are you using?

Comment: If you are using windows or osx you can try the free version of resolve.

Comment: @cegaton I am using Windows. I was wondering if there was better alternatives to Resolve?